# AppleScript - JavaScript execution on Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, applescript

Safari and Chrome can execute JavaScript via AppleScript

**Safari:**

```
 tell application "Safari"
    open location "http://example.com"
    activate
    do JavaScript "alert('example');" in current tab of first window
end tell
```

**Chrome:**

```
tell application "Google Chrome"
    open location "http://example.com"
    activate
    execute front window's active tab javascript "alert('example');"
end tell
```

**Is there a way to do this in Firefox?**

*Note: Same question for Opera is here: [AppleScript - JavaScript execution on Opera](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14383302/applescript-javascript-execution-on-opera)*

*I thought about asking them together, but I decided to ask two separate questions to be able to accept answers separately.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Running javascript using AppleScript in Firefox has not been implemented. [Bug Story](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=5704).
It is in New state and with no assignees. You could take that up :)

Comment: OMG. "Assigned To: Nobody; OK to take it and work on it." I don't think I will go that far.

Answer (score 3):

I have found a way to execute arbitrary javascript code on the current tab using the following AppleScript:

```
tell application "Firefox"
    activate
    set the clipboard to "(function(){alert(document.title)})();"

    tell application "System Events"
        keystroke "k" using {command down, option down} -- open console     
        delay 2
        keystroke "v" using {command down}
        keystroke return
        delay 1
        keystroke "i" using {command down, option down} -- close dev tools
        
    end tell
end tell
```

The above script shows the title of the current web page.

To execute your own code you just need to replace the javascript snippet between the curly braces:

```
alert(document.title)
```

with your own.