# AppleScript - JavaScript execution on Opera

Tags: javascript, applescript, opera

Safari and Chrome can execute JavaScript via AppleScript

**Safari:**

```
tell application "Safari"
    open location "http://example.com"
    activate
    do JavaScript "alert('example');" in current tab of first window
end tell
```

**Chrome:**

```
tell application "Google Chrome"
    open location "http://example.com"
    activate
    execute front window's active tab javascript "alert('example');"
end tell
```

**Is there a way to do this in Opera?**

*Note: Same question for Firefox is here: [AppleScript - JavaScript execution on Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14383039/applescript-javascript-execution-on-firefox)*

*I thought about asking them together, but I decided to ask two separate questions to be able to accept answers separately.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it would seem that Opera does not have an AppleScript dictionary

According to [this site](http://books.gigatux.nl/mirror/applescript/0596008503/applescripttmm-chp-9-sect-2.html):

> Opera (www.opera.com/download/) is a speedy, powerful, and expensive ($40) Web browser. If you're looking for AppleScript support, stay far away; Opera has none either.

That fact seems to be supported by the discussion [here](http://macscripter.net/viewtopic.php?id=43717).

---

That being said, you *might* be able to hack around that restriction (but it will be very ugly).

According to [here](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/8555):

> To indirectly reach the Console in Opera (checked on v9.6) the shortcut is CTRL + SHIFT + I

I think that is the Windows way, but Mac is probably just <kbd>command + shift + i</kbd>.

You get Opera to be the front window, then you use System Events to start typing. For example:

```
tell application "System Events"
    keystroke "l" using command down
    keystroke "c" using command down
end tell
```

(In other words, you should just use another browser.)

Comment: This is no longer true, Opera now has an AppleScript dictionary.